# How to webscrape from data-testid field?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having some trouble extracting text after data-testid element

This is the website element. I'm trying to extract Drunk Elephant

```html
<span class="product-brand css-738lkl e11u5ot719" data-testid="product-brand">Drunk Elephant</span>
```

I have tried the below codes but both just produced a None result

```html
brand = soup.find('span', class_='product-brand css-738lkl e11u5ot719', attrs={'data-testid': 'product-brand'})

brand = soup.find('span', class_='product-brand css-738lkl e11u5ot719')
```

Is there something I'm missing or different when there's a data-testid component?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In general you should use [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to get the text of an element

```
brand.get_text()
```

You could also use [`CSS SELECTORS`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to select it:

```
soup.select_one('[data-testid="product-brand"]').get_text()
```

or

```
soup.select_one('span[data-testid="product-brand"]').get_text()
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<span class="product-brand css-738lkl e11u5ot719" data-testid="product-brand">Drunk Elephant</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('[data-testid="product-brand"]').get_text()
```

---

To use it for multiple elements there is a `.select()` that ResultSet should be iterated:

```
for e in soup.select('[data-testid="product-brand"]'):
    print(e.get_text())
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to get this for multiple items on a page?
I belive the soup.select_one function only works for the exact item?

Comment: Use `select()` instead, while you like to work with multiple elements - Check additional  part of my answer.